# C++ Pointer to Pointer to chars in String-Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have to test the function

```
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, char **argv) {
[some code]
return command_arguments;
};
```

that takes a pointer to an array of command arguments and returns a Vector containing those arguments. The function works well. But I'm having trouble constructing such a pointer myself. The array is an array of strings, i.e. an array of array of chars. As far as I know, the pointer is supposed to point to the first pointer of the pointers pointing to the first letters of the strings (that sounds quite strange). What I need is an exemplary pointer **argv that I can pass to the function to see if it works. I know that there are a lot of similar questions on the internet, but I couldn't really find an answer that works for me. I would be very thankful if you could help me out, because I've been looking for an answer for several hours.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) command_arguments.emplace_back(argv[i]);

Comment: Should the question say,  how do I create a UT for this function?

Answer (score 2):

The command line arguments use both conventions to pass the number of arguments:

- it is explicitely passed in `argc`
- the `argv` array contains a null pointer as its last (useful) element

As you can construct a string for a `const char *`, code can be as simple as:

```
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> command_arguments;
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        command_arguments.push_back(std::string(argv[i]));
    }
    return command_arguments;
}
```

or (second convention):

```
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> command_arguments;
    for (const char **ix=argv; ix!=nullptr; ix++) {
        command_arguments.push_back(std::string(*ix++));
    }
    return command_arguments;
}
```

---

If you want to build such an array for tests, you can easily do it from literal strings:

```
const char *const_argv[] = { "foo", "fee", "bar", "baz", nullptr};  // add the last null
int my_argc = sizeof(my_argv)/sizeof(*my_argv) - 1;        // but do no count it
char ** my_argv = const_cast<char **>(const_argv);         // cast it
```

Beware: This code correctly declared `const_argv` to be an array of pointers to *const* characters, because a string literal is const, and uses `const_cast` to be able to pass it to above function. It is harmless because the function never try to change its parameters but the rule is that `const_cast` should be avoided if possible.

If you really need an array of non const strings, you must build the strings first and then the array:

```
char a1[] = "foo";
char a2[] = "fee";
char a3[] = "bar";
char a4[] = "baz";
char *argv[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4, nullptr};
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, I think I did a bad job expressing my question. I already have the function convert_arguments, but in order to test it, I need to construct an exemplary array and the pointer I can test the function with. This is what I have trouble with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It now makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

`char** argv` is really just a 2 dimensional array. You can create such an array via
`char** argv = new char*[argc];`. Then you can just loop over the argv array with `for(int i=0;i < argc; ++i)` and assaign whatever string you want to each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here the argc stores number of arguments passed and argv stored all the arguments.
You can do something like,

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
for (int counter=1;counter<argc;counter++)   //0th argument is the program name
{
    vec.push_back(argv[counter]); //push each string into vector
}
return vec;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a pointer of char arrays in the C fashion:

```c
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// borrowed from prehistoricpenguin
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, const char **argv) {
  return std::vector<std::string>(argv + 1, argv + argc);
}

bool test1(void) {
    int argc = 5;
    const char *argv[] = {"program_name", "some string", "another", "command", "ok", NULL };
    std::vector<std::string> myexpectedvector =  {"some string", "another","command", "ok" };
    std::vector<std::string> s = convert_arguments(argc, argv);
    return (s == myexpectedvector);
}

int main () {
    std::cout << test1() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks good point, I was answering on mobile while outside, not the best to compile and test, I adjusted my answer with a full example

Answer (score 0):

A one-line version:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, const char **argv) {
  return std::vector<std::string>(argv + 1, argv + argc);
}
```

Or even simpler with c++11 above

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> convert_arguments(int argc, const char **argv) {
  return {argv + 1, argv + argc};
}
```

Explanation:

We call the constructor for `std::vector` with two iterator ranges(pointer can be treat as an iterator), since argv is a pointer arry, the left range is `argv+1`, the right range is `argv + argc`.

For the `std::string` constructor, the `const char*` is passed.